# How to use CiviCRM Entity for searches with Facet API

Tags: entities, search, civicrm

I am trying to create a faceted search on CiviCRM contacts. I have created an index using the Search API module and the Facet API module, but currently the CiviCRM contacts can only be indexed on their ids, not their names. Obviously, that ain't so useful for humans to read...

For example, config/search/search_api/index/MYINDEXNAME/fields brings up the CiviCRM contacts as a possible field, but the default value is integer, not fulltext or string.

I was suggested CiviCRM Entity as a fix for this, but I can't quite work out how it could solve the problem -- would be very grateful for any pointers, or any other ideas!

Answer (score 0):

A wee bit of info here:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32169.0

but seems like u'll need to dig around and help build it

lobo

Answer (score 0):

I believe that CiviCRM Entity and Facet API can do this and it is well explained in [this blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/jackrabbithanna/civicrm-entity-using-drupal-search-and-facet-apis-with-civicrm-data)